# Java - Output Type (String, int, char, double)

Tags: string, types, char, int

Probably a very simple question for you guys but one that has been bugging me for the longest time. In my programming class when we are submitting the output of out code we are supposed to have appropriate formatting, for example:

"Hello World" for a string.

'g' for a character.

12 for int.

But recently I have been getting points off because I should have put quotes and other times when I shouldn't have. Take the following code:

```
public class MysterySoda {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      String soda = “coke”;
      String pop = “pepsi”; 
      String coke = “pop”;
      String pepsi = “soda”;
      String say = pop;

      carbonated(coke, soda, pop);
      carbonated(pop, pepsi, pepsi);
      carbonated(“pop”, pop, “koolaid”);
      carbonated(say, “say”, pop);
  }

public static void carbonated(String coke, String soda, String pop){        
   System.out.println(“say “ + soda + “ not “ + pop + “ or “ + coke);
}
```

The first line of output is:

say coke not pepsi or pop

But I thought it was:

"say coke not pepsi or pop"

Can someone please explain why the output is not a string?

Comment: It is a String. If you want quotes, you need to escape them like such: `\\"`.

Comment: Please also add tag Java to the question.

Comment: @FabianBigler Looks like Java to me.

Comment: @squiguy Dooh, you're right, luckily 5 minutes were not over. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The output is a string!** But the output itself will have no quotes included.

For example if you would print these lines, they would appear as:

- say coke not pepsi or pop

and **not** as:

- "say coke not pepsi or pop"

So if you wanted literally this output (quotes included) "say coke not pepsi or pop"

You would declare this variable like this in java:

```
string yourText = "\\"say coke not pepsi or pop\\""
```

Do you got it?

Comment: I understand that to literally print "say coke not pepsi or pop" you would need to use a series of escape sequences, but perhaps I phrased my question poorly. This is what my teacher wrote: Be sure to use appropriate type (e.g., "abc" for Strings in “quotes”)". So if the output is a string, we are to include quotes around it to indicate that our answer is indeed of the String type. So because the correct answer is not in quotes, that leads me to believe the output is not a string, but you guys say it is??

Comment: Then your teacher obviously tricksed himself.
Because this is 100% a string.

Comment: Thanks, I guess haha. I'll talk to my teacher and see what he says.